# MySQL Foreign Key Constraint Error (1215)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to run a `SQL` script to generate my database for a project through MySQL workbench but every time I attempt, I keep getting a `1215` error saying that it cannot add the foreign key constraint.

The error was in reference to the relationship below where I'm attempting to have the `id` of the `faculty` entity as a foreign key for a `grad_program` under the `director_id` field.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jupitercollege`.`faculty`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jupitercollege`.`faculty` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dept` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jupitercollege`.`grad_program`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jupitercollege`.`grad_program` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dept` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN',
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN',
  `director_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `director_id_idx` (`director_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `director_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`director_id`)
    REFERENCES `jupitercollege`.`faculty` (`id`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I've seen a lot of posts about this error but none have really been directly applicable to my scenario, unless I misunderstood them. Any aid in rectifying the situation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child table has `ON DELETE SET NULL`. MySql 5.6 documentation states

> If you specify a SET NULL action, make sure that you have not declared
>   the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.

Your director_id column has a not null constraint. Remove that constraint or remove the ON DELETE clause.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html